# Edit: Bootstrap panel-body that echoes a post title and acts as a link to the corresponding post

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, posts

**Edit:** I am attempting to get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efpyk.jpg), where my index.php generates a Bootstrap panel-body containing a corresponding post title each time a new post is made. I also want this panel-body to act as a link to the corresponding post (e.g. there is a post with the title 'SoFA at Market Day' and the panel-body on index.php contains the 'SoFA at Market Day' text and links to the 'SoFA on Market Day' post). Currently these panel-body's are contained in two separate columns, as shown in the code below.

Additionally, I would like these thumbnails to be arranged in descending order, with the newest post at the top left and the older posts following to the right, and then in the next row on the left, etc, as shown in the example image (meaning that 'SoFA at Market Day is the most recent post, 'Interview with...' is the 2nd most recent, and 'Cut Thumb ARI' is the 3rd most recent, 'Lecture by...' is the 4th most recent, etc, etc).

This is what my index.php currently looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package wpbootstrap-sofa
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="starter-template">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <div class="center-block">
            <a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/img/sofa-logo.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="UQ SoFA logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.center-block -->
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/">home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/blog-post-submissions/">submit blog post</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/contact/">contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/" target="_blank">store</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 -->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">SoFA at Market Day</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Cut Thumb ARI</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">GoMA Talks</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Interview with...</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Lecture by...</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Post #474</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row-->
</div>
<!-- /.starter-template-->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.background -->


<?php
get_footer();?>
```

I've really got no idea where to begin something like this, and I don't know if it's actually possible, so any help would be much appreciated. I've read through a lot of posts, but none seem to be trying to recreate what I am wanting to do with the post thumbnail echoing the post title. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You dont want the thumbnail to appear or you want title to appear over thumbnail?

Comment: Sorry, the way I've worded it might be a bit confusing.

Essentially I want to replicate the function of a post thumbnail, but instead of there being an image, I want there to be text which echoes a corresponding post title. I want this text to be contained within a panel-body div, and have a new panel-body generate containing the echoed post title that links to the corresponding post each time a new post is made.

If you look at the example image that I linked, it better illustrates what I mean.

Comment: imarkdesigns answer didn't help you? If it does, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use the thumbnail as your post excerpt display you should done this:

```
// Must be inside a loop.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
  echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/thumbnail-default.jpg" />';
}
```

if you wanted to customize the `the_post_thumbnail` you can add these attributes inside the code and it will look like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive responsive--full', 'title' => 'Feature image']);
```

`post-thumbnail` can be set via functions.php and give them specific sizes. you can declare different sets of dimension base on your needs. you need to set `add_image_size()`. Here's how you need to do it via functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail', 220, 180, true ); // 220 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

or you can set it right away with this:

```
the_post_thumbnail([150, 150, true], ['class' => 'img-responsive responsive--full', 'title' => 'Feature image']);
```

Hope this help you.

---

### 2nd Updated Version

Again, base on your title, I feel it was irrelevant to my statement here. So, I am guessing this could be what you are trying to achieve (if not, at least i tried my best).

Note: I mixed my answer with Yuri including my answer.

If you want the output, here's the static version: [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/imarkdesigns/pen/BWeywQ?editors=1100)

```
<div class="starter-template">
  <div id="header" class="container">
    <img src="http://www.logomarket.de/images/P/Germany%202-4-17-01.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Your Logo Here">
    <!-- This is a placeholder Image Only. Credit to LogoMarket.De -->
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="menu-list" class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#post">submit blog post</a></li>
          <li><a href="#events">events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#store" target="_blank">store</a></li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="post-list" class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Start Loop -->
          <?php $query = new WP_Query([ 'post_type' => ['post'], 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ]); ?>
          <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
              <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                  the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive', 'title' => 'Feature image']);
                } else {
                  echo '<img src="https://placem.at/things?w=500&h=300&txt=0&random=100">';
                }
              ?>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
          <!-- End Loop -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- #post-list -->
    </div>
    <!-- .row -->
  </div>
  <!-- #content -->
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you understand my question sorry, perhaps my wording wasn't the best.

I want the text inside the panel-body div to echo the corresponding post title whereby when you click on the panel-body it takes you to the corresponding post, and each time a new post is created, it appears on index.php

It's more like replicating the function of a post thumbnail, but instead of an image it's text.

Comment: Base on your details along with the example image, you would like to have 2 side by side column, 1st column will be your menu navigation while and 2nd column will be your post. Posts have thumbnail with post title as well. Is that what. you wanted to explain here? Question Title is irrelevant actually. Maybe you should change/update it.

Comment: I looked at the CodePen that you provided, but this isn't what I wish to do. I just edited my question and description, so maybe this can help to avoid confusion.

I want to have the function of a post thumbnail, but instead of an image, have it just be the post title contained in the panel-body. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, remove the content of `panel-body` move `panel-footer` content to `panel-body` and re-configure the panel box to your desired size as box. Then declare the `<a>` to your css as `display:block;width:300px;height:200px;` or to whatever size you would like to appear in the `panel-box`.

Comment: check imarkdesigns updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrGrNQ?editors=1100

Comment: I've checked the codepen but this doesn't explain how to have WordPress generate a panel-body that links to a corresponding article each time a post is made, and which contains the title of the article as its text. I don't know how I can explain this in simpler terms sorry.

Comment: **Edit**: Apologies. I'm just going through the edited answer that you've provided now @iMarkDesigns and I'm trying to integrate it into the structure that I already have in my index.php file. I just tested the loop and that seems to work in pulling the posts I've made to the home page

Comment: With some tinkering around with div names and changing id's to classes and closing divs, etc your solution worked! Thanks for your help @iMarkDesigns.

Initially I was left with two menus on mobile and one for desktop but I figured it out. There aren't enough characters in the comments space to show my exact .php code, so I've made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMdByE) here.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your exact problem but am hoping that you would need something like this. If you need side by side as you mentined in the DESC order then in the bootstrap you can use row and cover the area even using the loop. Just make sure you use order and orderby like below.

```
 query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'post_type' => 'post-type' ,'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC') );
    while ( have_posts()) : the_post();
 //all other codes.
```

and html part goes like this.

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package wpbootstrap-sofa
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="starter-template">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <div class="center-block">
            <a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/img/sofa-logo.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="UQ SoFA logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.center-block -->
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/">home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/blog-post-submissions/">submit blog post</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="http://www.uqsofa.com/contact/">contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/" target="_blank">store</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">SoFA at Market Day</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Interview with...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-body">Cut Thumb ARI</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Lecture by...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">    
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">GoMA Talks</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Post #474</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row-->
</div>
<!-- /.starter-template-->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.background -->


<?php
get_footer();?>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for...